# Get the JSON encode result from the Controller to View

Tags: php, highcharts, json, phalcon, pie-chart

I want to put a json encoded result (of `ManagementController.php`, `statisticAction`) to the Highchart syntax in view file (`stat.phtml`) in my Phalcon project. Was originally, in `stat.phtml` I used:

```
            ...
            ...
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: []
            }]
        } 
       $.getJSON('data/user_type.php', function(json) {
       options.series[0].data = json;
       chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

with the `data/user_type.php` placed in public folder.

`user_type.php`:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con) {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mockup_workspace", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name_type_user, total FROM v_ntype_user where id_admin=1");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$row[0] = $r[0];
$row[1] = $r[1];
array_push($rows,$row);
}
print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It works when I load, although the data is static. But it still uses **native PHP syntax**, so I want to use that logic in Managementcontroller.  Then I found the issue that `$.getJSON` that still need URL json file (like `data/user_type.php`), while I was using ManagementController (myController/actionController).
So, what if I want to bring it from the Controller?

`ManagementController.php`

```
<?php

 namespace workspace_mockup_2\Controllers;
 use workspace_mockup_2\Models\VnTypeUser as nTypeUser;
 use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

 class ManagementController extends Controller {
  ...
  public function statisticAction() {
    $id_admin = $this->session->get('auth');

    // User Type
    $typeUser = nTypeUser::find('id_admin="' . $id_admin . '"');    
    $rows = array();
    foreach($typeUser as $t) {
        $row[0] = $t->name_type_user;
        $row[1] = $t->total;
        array_push($rows,$row);
    }
    echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    $this->view->pick("/frontend/user_management_page/stat");
}
```

I've been looking for a way, such put this in that Controller,

```
...
$printjson = json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$this->view->printjs = $printjson;
```

and put `$printjs` variable to replace `$.getJSON('data/user_type.php', ...` in `stat.phtml`, but it did not work as well.
Please help :(

Thank's..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an ajax call then you need to return back the results from your controller with an echo or a print. If not, then you need to set your variable (that contains the data) in the view.

Examples:
Controller - set a variable in the view

```
namespace workspace_mockup_2\Controllers;
use workspace_mockup_2\Models\VnTypeUser as nTypeUser;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class ManagementController extends Controller
{

    public function statisticsAction()
    {
        // User Type
        $typeUser = nTypeUser::find('id_admin="' . $id_admin . '"');
        $rows = array();
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($typeUser)) {
            $row[0] = $r[0];
            $row[1] = $r[1];
            array_push($rows,$row);
        } 
        $this->view->pick("/frontend/user_management_page/stat");
        $this->view->setVar('data', json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
    }
}
```

View

```
options.series[0].data = <?php echo data; ?>;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Controller - return data as AJAX

```
namespace workspace_mockup_2\Controllers;
use workspace_mockup_2\Models\VnTypeUser as nTypeUser;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class ManagementController extends Controller
{
    public function statisticsaction()
    {
        $this->view->setRenderLevel(PhView::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);
        $this->response->setContentType('text/json');

        // User Type
        $typeUser = nTypeUser::find('id_admin="' . $id_admin . '"');
        $rows = array();
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($typeUser)) {
            $row[0] = $r[0];
            $row[1] = $r[1];
            array_push($rows,$row);
        } 
        // This will return raw JSON suitable for AJAX calls
        echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
    }

}
```

View

```
            ...
            ...
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: []
            }]
        } 
       $.getJSON('management/statistics', function(json) {
       options.series[0].data = json;
       chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

**NOTE**: Please remove all references to mysql_* commands and either replace them with PDO or mysqli or even Phalcon's Models. mysql_* has been deprecated

Comment: Initially I tried the set a variable, but `<?php echo $data; ?>` Or `print $data;` in view, it doesn't work. Why this is so?
Yet when I check if its controller file unreadable or not in its view, it has been read so variable it should be parsed..

Comment: Then I tried to use the returns the data as AJAX. When I saw `$this->view->setRenderLevel(PhView::LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW);` seems I have to include
`use Phalcon\Mvc\View as PhView;` in the controller. But the chart is still not works. And appeared parse-error, I do not know where it comes..

Comment: For Ajax all you have to do in your action is `echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));` This will send it to the view. You need to include the PhView use statement because you are using the LEVEL_ACTION_VIEW variable. Alternatively you can also disable the view at the top of the function.

Comment: Thank's!! :) I had it done! I've used variable in the view. It was just my mistake, wrong  to do query so I updated my question again. Thank you for your help, very helpful.